# How to create sortable tree with reactjs DND? (How to create recursive multi lists in react-beautiful-dnd? )

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd, treelist

In this codesandbox you can see a tree of elements that you can drag each one of them, but the problem you can drop each element in spsefec dropable area.

- I tried to add `{...prov.droppableProps}` to the draggable div to be draggable and dropable at the same time but it didn't work.
- I tried to create recursive multi lists (multi-columns) but it returns too many errors with me despite I strongly believe that it is the solution to my problem, but maybe I didn't do it right.
  [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dnd-zjdjd?file=/src/App.js)